# org.json.JSONException: No value for id

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to parse json with an edittext, make it match for an id, and load the data it carries in textview. Im not really sure how to go about this, whether im using the right JSON, or if im using the right way to determine the most efficiet way to handle this. When i enter '5' in the edittext, i get the error mentioned below:

Error:

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for id
```

The JSON from url being parsed:

```
{
"id": "5",
"first_name": "Larry",
"last_name": "Gonzales",
"email": "lgonzales4@msu.edu",
"country": "Japan",
"ip_address": "242.198.195.241"
```

}

Java:

```
        try {


            JSONObject e = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject jsonobjectidloader = e.getJSONObject(TAG_ID);

      if (jsonobjectidloader.equals(xyz)){

                uid.setText(id3);
                id3 = jsonobjectidloader.getString(TAG_ID);
                name1.setText(fname);
                fname = jsonobjectidloader.getString(TAG_FIRST_NAME);
                name2.setText(lname);
                lname = jsonobjectidloader.getString(TAG_LAST_NAME);
                email1.setText(email);
                email = jsonobjectidloader.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                ipaddres.setText(ipa);
                ipa = jsonobjectidloader.getString(TAG_IP);
                cou.setText(country);
                country = jsonobjectidloader.getString(TAG_COUNTRY);
```

I hope you guys can help me with this, im really stumped right now.

Comment: `e = new JSONObject();` ... `e` is empty and has no "id" property ...

Comment: Okey, but how should i wrap it up with the json i have now? Suppose i wanted to parse the json with the way i mentioned? How would i go about this?

Answer (score 2):

```
JSONObject e = new JSONObject(response.toString());

String id3 = e.getString(TAG_ID);
```

Response is your json from server

Answer (score 1):

Use following code.

```
JSONObject jsonobjectidloader= new JSONObject(YOUR_JSON_STRING);

 if (jsonobjectidloader.equals(xyz)){

            id3 = jsonobjectidloader.getString(TAG_ID);
            uid.setText(id3);
            fname = jsonobjectidloader.getString(TAG_FIRST_NAME);
            name1.setText(fname);
            lname = jsonobjectidloader.getString(TAG_LAST_NAME);
            name2.setText(lname);
            email = jsonobjectidloader.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
            email1.setText(email);
            ipa = jsonobjectidloader.getString(TAG_IP);
            ipaddres.setText(ipa);
            country = jsonobjectidloader.getString(TAG_COUNTRY);
            cou.setText(country);
```

Comment: Unless id3 has a value before parsing the JSON, I would think calling uid.setText(id3) before assigning a value to id3 won't work.

Comment: I didn't have any issue, just wanted to point out potential errors that could arise from the code. Much better now, I think, voted up ;)

Comment: @2Dee i just copy/paste his code without checking it. By the way thanks for your pointing such error. Nice catch.. :)

Answer (score 0):

just use it as

```
String json = '{"id":"5","first_name":"Larry","last_name":"Gonzales","email":"lgonzales4@msu.edu","country":"Japan","ip_address":"242.198.195.241"}';
e = new JSONObject(json);
.....
```

you need to actually provide the string to jsonboject constructor as argument.